# Why does my code not iterate over each line? There is a key error "\n" despite stripping off(.txt input fed in using .read())

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding, keyerror

I have a .txt file of DNA sequences in the format shown below:

```
>seq1
ATATAT
>seq2
GGGGG
>seq3
TTTTT
```

Using re.sub, I have removed the lines with ">seq" numbers like this, to have an input of just lines of DNA bases A, G, C and T like this, and then stripped the "\n" as follows:

```
ATATAT
GGGGG
TTTTT
```

```
import re
test = re.sub('\ |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|>|s|e|q|:', "", holder)
newone = test.rstrip("\n")
```

I would then like to use this as input into my one hot encoder, which is encased within an if statement (there is an if statement to check if any unexpected letters are present in the DNA sequence). So far it looks like this:

```
for line in newone:

#if undesirable letters are present in sequence, an error message is displayed
    if (bool(result)) == True:
        print("The input sequence is invalid.")

#if sequence is in the correct format, proceed with one hot encoding

    else:   
     #mapping of bases to integers as a dictionary
        bases = "ATCG"
        base_to_integer = dict((i, c) for c, i in enumerate(bases))

    #encoding input sequence as integers
        integer_encoded = [base_to_integer[y] for y in newone]

    #one hot encoding
        onehot_encoded = list()
        for value in integer_encoded:
            base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]
            base[value] = 1
            onehot_encoded.extend(base)
        print(onehot_encoded)
```

I can see this error in the shell, but I am not sure why, because I think I have indicated in my code that "\n" needs to be stripped:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Agatha\Documents\testtt.py", line 38, in <module>
    integer_encoded = [base_to_integer[y] for y in newone]
  File "C:\Users\Agatha\Documents\testtt.py", line 38, in <listcomp>
    integer_encoded = [base_to_integer[y] for y in newone]
KeyError: '\n'
```

I would like my program to iterate the code over each line of my input file, but I am not sure if my for loop ("for line in newone") will achieve this if the \n is stripped, and I cannot work out how I could rearrange this to make it work. 
I am aiming to have my output in this kind of format, where each one-hot-encoded sequence is displayed on a separate line, e.g:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I would appreciate any advice on what the source of this error is and how I could go about fixing it.

Comment: maybe try `test.replace("\n", "")` instead

Comment: Thank you so much @BlueRineS, this worked in the sense that the code now recognises the new lines in the text! In the meantime, I will try to figure out what is wrong with my for loop, as now the output is not on separate lines and is repeated several times in the shell.

Comment: Did it work? @agatha

Comment: Although it seems like getting rid of the "\n" at that stage in my code is preventing me from achieving the output I would like to have, as it also gets rid of any distinction between the sequences - it results in them being one-hot-encoded all together in one string.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use the `.split()` method to create a list from the text you read.

```py
test = re.sub('\ |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|>|s|e|q|:', "", holder)
newone = test.split("\n")
```

at this point `newone` will look like `['', 'ATATAT', '', 'GGGGG', '', 'TTTTT', '']` so to strip out the extra spaces:

```py
newone = [x for x in newone if x != '']
```

Now to the error you are receiving, it is because you in your list comprehension (line 38 of your code) you are using `newone` instead of `line`. Each letter of `line` is an key of your dictionary `base_to_integer` but the KeyError you get is because `\n` is not a Key in the dictionary. Even after making the change I suggest above you will get an error:

```py
KeyError: 'ATATAT'
```

So you should change this line to:

```
integer_encoded = [base_to_integer[y] for y in line]
```

Fixing this gives me:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the idea of a splitting approach will make the code much better. However, when I try ```newone = [x for in newone if x != ""]```, I am getting a syntax error, is there a little typo here?

Comment: I have managed to get it to work now, using ```newone = [x for x in newone if x]```